# why the code in /arch/arm/cpu/armv7m/start.s is very little? Is it complete?

Tags: gcc, makefile, arm, stm32, u-boot

In the code of  arm/cpu/armv7m/start.s in u-boot2016.01 is too few compared to others.

```
.globl  reset
.type reset, %function
reset:
    b   _main

.globl  c_runtime_cpu_setup
c_runtime_cpu_setup:
    mov pc, lr
```

Is it complete?

Comment: what did you find when you looked at _main, or better yet build something and look at how reset goes to _main, which probably does a number of things then eventually hits main

Comment: "too few compared to others" it doesn't sound very scientific. Is there an issue ? Do you encounter any limitation or bug ? Where this `start.s`comes from anyway, a trusted source ?

Answer (score 0):

it is far not enough for the compliant implementation. At least there should be initialization of the initialized static storage objects and zeroing not initialized static storage ones.